# SQL Group by prevents summing across multiple records

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to sum the amount paid across multiple entries in the Payment table and show who the buyers were for that Order

so if two people made payments on one order it would show their combined payments and show who the people who made the payment were. So if Bob and Sue made 10 dollar payments on a 30 dollar bill it would show

```
Order Buyer Paid Owes  
1     Bob   20   10
1     Sue   20   10
```

but i'm currently at

```
Order    Paid Owes  
1        20   10
```

How do I add in the buyers? possibly with a join?
Currently I have.

```
Select Order.Orderid, sum(Payment.amount) as "Paid", Order.Price-sum(Payment.amount) as "Owes"
from order, payment
where payment.orderId = order.orderid 
group by (order.orderid, order.price)
```

payment has a buyerId and orderid as foreign keys since it is an m to n relation.

Comment: Your queries have no `group by`.

Comment: Saw that I didn't copy that over from my code, edited thanks.

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: Is the buyer field in the payment table or a separate table?

Comment: Buyer its own table so would want a sort of buyer.buyerid = payment.buyerid, but if i put buyer.name in the groupby then it only sums the payments that one buyer made not all the payments for that order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention in your comment when you join the buyer it does not give you the desired output which is the sum of all payments. To get the buyers and the sum of all payments joining another instance of the payments table and using that to calculate the sum will do the trick.

```
SELECT
    Order.Orderid,
    Buyer.Name,
    SUM(PaymentSum.amount) AS 'Paid',
    Order.Price-SUM(PaymentSum.amount) AS 'Owes',
FROM
    Order
    JOIN Payment
        ON Order.Orderid = Payment.Orderid
    JOIN Buyer
        ON Payment.BuyerId Buyer.BuyerId
    JOIN Payment AS PaymentSum
        ON Order.Orderid = PaymentSum.Orderid
GROUP BY
    Order.Orderid,
    Order.Price,
    Buyer.Name
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! That's exactly what I was trying to do. Glad you can use multiple joins like that.